# UICollectionViewController only one cell working properly others are blank

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm building an app that displays gifs in a UICollectionView. I am using Alamofire as well as FLAnimatedImage from FlipBoard. I get an list of gif urls and then set the fetched image.

When I run this, only the first cell on my first page is working properly. When I scroll to the second page, the same (reused cell) is the only one working. I checked this via printing the memory address of the cell, and it is the only one showing the proper image.

I don't think it is an issue with FLAnimatedImage as I tried with normal UIImage's and it still had this behavior. I suspect it has to do with my Subclass of UICollectionViewCell. In my storyboard I tried both referencing my subclass of UICollectionViewCell and not having a UICollectionViewCell in the interface.

Gif Data Model

```
class GifData : NSObject {
let id : String
let url : String

init(id: String, url: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.url = url
}}
```

Collection View Controller

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView!.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: myReuseIdentifier)

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search",
        parameters: ["q":"hello", "api_key": "dc6zaTOxFJmzC", "limit" : "29"])
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                let gifData = (JSON.valueForKey("data") as! [NSDictionary])
                    .map {
                    GifData(id: $0["id"] as! String, url: $0["images"]!["fixed_width_small_still"]!!["url"] as! String)
                }

                self.gifUrls.addObjectsFromArray(gifData)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
    }
}
```

Collection View Data Source

```
     override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return gifUrls.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cakeReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CakeCollectionViewCell

    if (self.gifUrls.count != 0) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, (self.gifUrls.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! GifData).url)
            .response(completionHandler: { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
                cell.animatedImageView.animatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: data!)
            })
        return cell
    }

    return cell
}
```

My CollectionViewCell

```
class CakeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var animatedImageView = FLAnimatedImageView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.animatedImageView.frame = self.frame
    self.contentView.addSubview(animatedImageView)
    self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.animatedImageView.animatedImage = nil
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code you posted, but first the answer the specific question you have:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.animatedImageView.frame = self.frame
    self.animatedImageView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight] // add this line
    self.contentView.addSubview(animatedImageView)
    self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

I suspect that if you put a breakpoint inside your cell's init function you would find that its initial frame size is zero. Adding an auto resize mask will allow your image view to change size when the content view changes size.

For another major problem I think you will find with your code... Imagine if a cell gets reused before the GET request completes and the second GET request for the reused cell completes before the first one does... You would end up showing the wrong gif for that cell. This won't happen often, but I expect it will happen and will be impossible to track down if you don't know it's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately the auto resize mask did not work, but I managed to fix this problem by not using UICollectionViewController and just used a normal UIViewController and manually added a collection view myself. For some reason this implementation worked with the same code I had before. ... For the problem you mentioned, I ended up moving the GET requests after I GET from the api query and simply set those gifs data into an NSMapTable with the corresponding index. Then in my collectionDataSource I set the image if the index of the NSMapTable is not nil. Is this better?

Comment: Odd. I got curious and duplicated your project... Even if I pre-load all the gifs before calling `reloadData()` the images failed to display. Odd... Oh well... It's more flexible to have a collection view inside a normal view controller anyway. As for the other issue, (1) a map table is an odd choice for Swift, why not just use a dictionary? (2) even with this idea, cells that appear before their image is loaded won't display their image. I suggest you move this issue to another question, rather than try to talk about it in the comments.